# Reading from the command line in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, shell

I am trying to run the following mplayer command in rails using session:

```
mplayer -identify -vo null -ao null -frames 0 text.mov
```

I use require "session" and the following code works great in an individual ruby file.

```
mb = "mplayer"
    mi = "-identify -vo null -ao null -frames 0"
    dimensions_bitrate = Hash.new

    stdout, stderr = '', ''
    shell = Session::Shell.new
    shell.execute "#{mb} #{mi} #{filename}", :stdout => stdout, :stderr => stderr

    vars = (stdout.split(/\n/).collect! { |o| o if o =~ /^ID_/ } ).compact!

    vars.each { |v|
            a, b = v.split("=")
            eval "@#{a.to_s.downcase} = \"#{b}\""       
            if a == "ID_VIDEO_WIDTH"
                    dimensions_bitrate[0] = b.to_i
            elsif a == "ID_VIDEO_HEIGHT"
                    dimensions_bitrate[1] = b.to_i
            elsif a == "ID_VIDEO_BITRATE"
                    dimensions_bitrate[2] = b.to_i
            end
    }
```

HOWEVER, I am unable to load the session gem into ROR.  I am not sure what the problem is.  If I add require "session", I get the following error:

```
no such file to load -- session
```

I figure I am missing something relatively straightforward.

Any ideas?

Comment: which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: 1.9.2. - it works fine, I just can't require 'session' inside of rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this to work, so I did the following:

```
stdout = %x["mplayer" "-identify" "-vo" "-ao" "null" "-frames" "0" "#{filename}"]
    vars = (stdout.split(/\n/).collect! { |o| o if o =~ /^ID_/ } ).compact!
    vars.each { |v|
            a, b = v.split("=")
            eval "@#{a.to_s.downcase} = \"#{b}\""       
            if a == "ID_VIDEO_WIDTH"
                    dimensions_bitrate[0] = b.to_i
            elsif a == "ID_VIDEO_HEIGHT"
                    dimensions_bitrate[1] = b.to_i
            elsif a == "ID_VIDEO_BITRATE"
                    dimensions_bitrate[2] = b.to_i
            end
    }
```

and it worked great.  hope this is of use to someone running command line from ROR.  The key is to set each parameter as a string.